# Pop up bugged doesn't show all the buttons

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a simple Pop up on this project, while the code works on some device, but there seems to be a bug on some devices.

### This is the XML

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Silakan pilih yang ingin di rating"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_atasan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="Atasan"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sekawan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="Sekawan"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_bawahan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="Bawahan"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### This is the java code on the fragment

```
private void popUpRatingType() {

    //instantiate the popup.xml layout file
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_rate_karyawan, null);

    //casting buttons
    btnAtasan = customView.findViewById(R.id.btn_atasan);
    btnBawahan = customView.findViewById(R.id.btn_bawahan);
    btnSekawan = customView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sekawan);

    //instantiate popup window
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(customView, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //display the popup window
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(contentFrame, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

*Remove popup on outside click*

```
    // Removes default background.
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    // Closes the popup window when touch outside.
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.update();
}
```

On some devices it looks okay, like this :

[image]

But I don't know how on some devices (**this is on Nougat**) looks like this :

[image]

Comment: try giving the parent LinearLayout height as wrap_content

Comment: @RahulKhurana tried it didn't work sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void popUpRatingType() {

    //instantiate the popup.xml layout file
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_temp, null);

    //casting buttons
    //instantiate popup window
    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(customView, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //display the popup window
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(customView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    // Closes the popup window when touch outside.
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.update();
}
```

Comment: popupWindow.showAtLocation(customView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

Comment: PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(customView, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);   try this

Comment: If the layout height is MATCH_PARENT, the pop up fill the whole screen